# how to handle push firebase notification click event when the application is in background?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, push

I'm New in Android.

When the application is open and notification came from firebase and click the notification then it open the Notification Activity but when the application is in foreground/background and notification came and click the notification then it automatically open the mainActivity.

I'm broadcasting the data from FirebaseMessagingService.class to Main Activity.

Why?

My code is below.

**MainActivity**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                    .registerReceiver(mHandler,new IntentFilter("Pakage_name_FCM-MESSAGE"));
             }

        private BroadcastReceiver mHandler = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                Log.d("MainActivity-title",title);
                Log.d("MainActivity-message",message); 
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            // Unregister the Broadcast receiver
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mHandler);
        }
    }
```

**FirebaseNotificationIdService.Class**

```
public class FirebaseNotificationIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String REG_TOKEN = "REG_TOKEN";

    @Override   // each time a new created and system call this method
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String recent_token= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(REG_TOKEN,recent_token);
    }
}
```

**FirebaseMessagingService.class**

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d("Remote Form",remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // check if the message contains data...
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size()> 0){
               Log.d("Message Data", "Message Data---"+remoteMessage.getData() );

            String title=remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            String message=remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

            Intent intent = new Intent("package_name_FCM-MESSAGE");
            intent.putExtra("title",title);
            intent.putExtra("message",message);
            Log.d("INTENT-TITLE",title);
            Log.d("INTENT-MESSAGE",message);
            LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
            localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

        //check if the message contain notification

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            Log.d("Message Body","---"+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    //Display the notification
    private void sendNotification(String body) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0/*Request code*/,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        //Set sound
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notifiBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notifiBuilder.setContentTitle("Aadhaar Update");
        notifiBuilder.setContentText(body);
        notifiBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notifiBuilder.setSound(notificationSound);
        notifiBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0/*Id of Notification*/,notifiBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**Minifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".FirebaseNotificationIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".NotificationActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You should use implementation of WakefulBroadcastReceiver instead of FirebaseMessagingService

```
   public class NotificationsReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //process data from intent
            abortBroadcast();
        }
   }
```

In your manifest

```
    <receiver
            android:name=".fcm.NotificationsReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: it is helpful to me. if i want to open a specific page the what i have to do? see my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797486/open-specific-page-using-firebase-api

Comment: `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is deprecated as of Android O (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/legacy/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver)