# open specific page using firebase api

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework

I am sending push notification to devices using below code.

```
      var nTitle = "New message from " + $rootScope.clients_firstName;
      var to = "DeviceToken is here";
      var notification = {
        'title': nTitle,
        //'body': 'Click here to more details...',
        'icon': 'firebase-logo.png',
        'click_action': 'openapp'
      };

      var key = 'your key';
      fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {
      'method': 'POST',
        'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'key=' + key,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      'body': JSON.stringify({
        'notification': data,
        'to': to
      })
      }).then(function(response) {
        //console.log("res ", response);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("err ", error);
     });
```

push notification sends on device successfully.

But when I click on notification the specific page should be open.

For example `'click_action' : 'openapp/somepage'`

Then the 'somepage' should be open when I click on pushnotification.

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="openapp" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

My project structure

```
--platforms
--plugins
--www
  --app
    --about
      --about.html
      --about.ctrl.js
    --product
      --product.html
      --product.ctrl.js
  --css
  --js
  --lib
  index.html
```

If I click on notification and I want to open product or about page then what I have to do?

What is wrong here? Please tell me the proper solution.

Answer (score 4):

For notifications to be clickable when your app is in the background, you need the `click_action` attribute in your notification payload.

Please check this [section](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjP-vesl-rUAhXMP48KHQ-nD9sQygQIKDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fhttp-server-ref%23notification-payload-support&usg=AFQjCNEQeBMYQX-1IYsUDKnjj7OtYhlFIA) of the Firebase docs.

Also, when you define the `click_action` attribute, you will also need a corresponding `<action>` attribute in the `<intent-filter>` of the activity that you wish to launch.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hi8IPLNq59o) explains it in quite a detailed manner.

Though, please note that you can not set the `click__action` attribute if you're sending notifications from the Firebase Console. You can only do so if you send a notification from your own Admin server or using Firebase Cloud Functions.

Lastly, in the activity that is launched, you can set additional `Data` using the data attribute ( also shown in the same doc that I linked above ). And when you launch your app by clicking on a notification, you can  obtain the notification data using `getIntent()`. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40185654/7626492) for more details on how to do that.

**Edit after question update :-**

Instead of putting that `<intent-filter>` in `MainActivity`, put the filter in the `<activity>` tag of the activity that you want to open when the notification is clicked. An example is the following :-

```
<activity android:name="ProductDetailsActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="openapp" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Now that your specified activity opens, you can get information from the `data` part of your notification using `getIntent()`.

For example, if your notification payload has the following structure,

```
payload = {
  notification: {
    title: `You ordered a new product`,
    click_action : 'HANDLE_NOTIFICATION',

  },
  data : {
        product_id : 'ABC98292',
        type : `Clothes`,
        product_name : 'Cotton spring shirt'
    }
};
```

Then you can get the `product_id` from the notification using `getIntent().getStringsExtra("product_id")` and so on.

This way, you'll be opening the required activity, and can populate it with the relevant details obtained from your notification without using any additional frameworks.

Comment: my above code is working. and when i clicked on notification the app is also opened. but i want to open a particular page. means if the notification is "product" related then the "product" page will open, if the notification is "chat" related then the "chatting" page will open. understand?

Comment: You posted only the `<intent_filter>` part of your manifest. Tell me which `Activity` that filter belongs to. Or just post the `<activity>` part of the manifest in your answer.

Comment: now i got an error Uncaught ReferenceError: getIntent is not defined.

Comment: Use this `this.cordova.getActivity().getIntent(); `

Comment: again error `Uncaught TypeError: this.cordova.getActivity is not a function`

Comment: Try this.getActivity().getIntent();

Comment: error `Uncaught TypeError: this.getActivity is not a function`

Comment: Look, I do not know your entire code or how well versed you are with ionic, Cordova and Android. So I really can't suggest you a pin-pointed method. But, since you're using ionic with Android, there has got to be a way for you to access your activity context and retrieve the intent details, because activities and intents are fundamental to Android.

Answer (score 2):

I know that you ask about Ionic 1. But I only know for Ionic 2. Hope this will help you.

I think you should add information about what page you need to open in additional data section of your notice. Something like this:

```
'body': JSON.stringify({
        'notification': data,
        'to': to,
        'data' : {
           'action' : 'Needed page'
        }
      })
```

And then you should catch it on the subscribe method. Something like that:

```
fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data=>{
  console.log("data", data);
  if (data['action'] && data['action'] == 'Needed page'){
    this.navCtrl.push('Needed page'); //Use Navigation controller to open needed page
  }
})
```

For native cordova FCM plugin:

```
FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
    console.log("data", data);
    if (data['action'] && data['action'] == 'Needed page'){
      this.navCtrl.push('Needed page'); //Use Navigation controller to open needed page
    }
});
```

Comment: i am usign firebase api. will this work? see my code, it is very simple.

Comment: You need to try and use console log. I think first example about push notice body will work. Second no because I wrote example for Ionic 2. But the algoritm is the the same for ionic 1. You just need to subscribe on notification via fcm cordova plugin https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm. Use onNotification method.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ionic Push Plugin you can receive using

```
$scope.$on('cloud:push:notification', function(event, data) {
        var msg = data.message;
        var appState = msg.app;
        var appAsleep = appState.asleep;
        var appClosed = appState.closed;


        if (appAsleep || appClosed) {               
            $state.go("your state");
        } else {
           //if app is open while receiving push
        }

    });
```

Comment: if i used plugin then i could help. but i am not using any plugin. i used firebase api.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your url in the push payload and use the following code to open the the specific screen referred by that url:

```
$rootScope.$on("$cordovaLocalNotification:click", function(notification, state) {
    var data = JSON.parse(state.data);
    window.location.href = data.url;
});
```

Comment: i am not using any plugin. i used firebase api.

Answer (score 0):

You asked me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42696067/3858030). 
If you use my solution and creating notifications manually in `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method, you must put pending intent to notification builder.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
//init builder with icon, text, any other params

Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //it is needed if you creating an activity from not activity context
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

Notification notification = builder.build();
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(notificationId, notification);
```

Comment: Right now, if i close the app from any page/view. and when i received a notification then app opens from a default page( the page that last open). but i want to open my own page, not the default page.